# FullCalendar time on vertical axis

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to change the time on the vertical axis?
I’m trying to make school timetable calendar with 45 min slots, starts 8:30 – 09:15, 09:20 – 10:05 and so on.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

add the option `slotMinutes: 45` to make the intervals 45 minutes and set start time by adding the option `minTime: '8:30am'`

like this:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    slotMinutes: 45,
    minTime: '8:30am',
    //the reset of options.....
});
```

link to documentation: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/